# Regular Expression to match two words in either order with a specific third word between them

Tags: regex

I looked through a lot of other questions and just didn't quite see what I think would work for me.  Basically I want to match three words exactly: "cat", "and", "dog" where "and" is *always* in the middle but "cat" and "dog" can be on either side.  I have used lookarounds to match "cat" and "dog" in either order, but I can't figure out how to integrate a test for the "and" in the middle.  What I currently have is this:

`^(?=.*\bcat\b)(?=.*\bdog\b).*$`

but this accepts any word between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If duplicates are not a problem,
\b((cat\sand\sdog)|(dog\sand\scat))\b
is the simplest solution, otherwise
\b((cat\sand\sdog)|(dog\sand\scat))\b

Comment: Definitely answered the question.  Only thing is that I think both of those regular expressions are the same, so if there was a second possible answer I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: You are correct - the problems of "cut-and-paste". 
\b(cat|dog)\sand\s(cat|dog)\b
is the second (simpler) regex